# Regexp word between the braces

Tags: regex

I'm writing custom code static analysis rules.

I want to find such override functions, which **don't** have super function call.

For example, regexp should find this:

```
override func testFunc(num: Int) {
   print()
}
```

But, **do not** find this:

```
override func testFunc(num: Int) {
   print()
   super.testFunc(num: num)
   print()
}
```

We should keep in mind that function can contain extra block inside. So, we have also **not find** this:

```
override func testFunc(num: Int) {
   print()
   super.testFunc(num: num)
   let block = {
       print("inside block")
   }
   print()
}
```

And we should not be interested in super function call inside blocks. Only inside that function.

I wrote this: `override func\s(\w*)\(.*?\{.*?super\.\1.*?\}`

But it is not consider blocks and it find functions where **is** super function call. And I don't know how to invert this.

Comment: Are you already parsing this code? The solution to your problem will be easier if you can traverse the parse tree instead.

Comment: [This is not a job for regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets)